# How to print canvas withouth showing printing dialog

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to C#. I'm currently develop a kiosk software using WPF.

I wanted to print a bill inside a canvas, i had created a white background's canvas to print it.

Here are my code to print :

```
 //The address read from user input
 COAChequeChequeAddress1Printed.Content = premiseType + " " + premiseNo + " " + premiseName;
 COAChequeChequeAddress2Printed.Content = streetOne;
 COAChequeChequeAddress3Printed.Content = streetTwo;
 COAChequeChequeAddress4Printed.Content = poskod + " " + area + " " + town;
 COAChequeChequeAddress5Printed.Content = state;

 COAChequeContactNumberPrinted.Content = contactNo;


 COAChequePrintedImage.Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(Properties.Settings.Default.ICChequeImagePath)));

 if ((bool)Printdlg.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())  
 {
      COAChequeFormPrinted.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
      //Printdlg.PrintVisual(COAChequeFormPrinted, "COA Cheque FORM");

      //Hide every form and show print success page
      COAChequeFormPrinted.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
      COAFormCheque.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
      COAFormTransfer.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
      printCOAChequeForm.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
      printCOATransferForm.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
      PrintingMessageCanvas.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
 }
```

If i comment out the  `if ((bool)Printdlg.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())`  it won't prompt the printing dialog, but my canvas label's content become empty when printed.

If i used the showdialog function, all my canvas label content is show up when print.

Is there anything i can changed in the setting or any code can help ?
Please guide me through this. Thanks

Comment: Where are you doing the actual printing? In that commented line? Maybe you should defer the execution of the last lines, moving them to an asynchronous call

Comment: You should render your UI in code before printing. (eg `Measure` & `Arrange` methods.)

Comment: @DeMama Thanks, i had suggessfully done it